# Pinax-referrals in Django

Tags: python, pinax

Am using [Pinax-referrals](https://anafero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) to implement referral system in my django app

How do I use `PINAX_REFERRALS_REDIRECT_ATTRIBUTE` in my settings.py

doing this `PINAX_REFERRALS_REDIRECT_ATTRIBUTE = reverse_lazy('home')` gives me `NoReverseMatch` Error

Comment: You should specify the url path to redirect to like '/home/'